# Serilog.Sink.Splunk version 3.3 does not have outputTemplate when writing to EventController

Tags: c#, serilog

Previously in version 2.0 Serilog.Sink.Splunk has outputTemplate built-in

```
public static LoggerConfiguration EventCollector(..., string outputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}", ....);
```

but when I use the newer version which is 3.3.0.0, the parameter is missing.

How could I enforce my outputTemplate in the version 3.3?

Comment: any solution do you have?